# Adding a value into a DenseVector in PySpark

Tags: python, vector, pyspark, type-conversion

I have a DataFrame that I have processed to be like:

```
+---------+-------+
| inputs  | temp  | 
+---------+-------+
| [1,0,0] | 12    |
+---------+-------+
| [0,1,0] | 10    |
+---------+-------+
...
```

`inputs` is a column of DenseVectors. `temp` is a column of values. I want to append the DenseVector with these values and create one column, but I am not sure how to start. Any tips for this desired output:

```
+---------------+
| inputsMerged  | 
+---------------+
| [1,0,0,12]    | 
+---------------+
| [0,1,0,10]    |
+---------------+
...
```

EDIT: I am trying to use the `VectorAssembler` method but my resulting array is not as intended.

Comment: How do you want to append the values? Something like `[1,0,0,12], [0,1,0,10]`?

Comment: Yup - I'll edit that in for clarity, but that's how I'd like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
df.show()
+-------------+----+
|       inputs|temp|
+-------------+----+
|[1.0,0.0,0.0]|  12|
|[0.0,1.0,0.0]|  10|
+-------------+----+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- inputs: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- temp: long (nullable = true)
```

*Import*:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

Create the udf to merge the Vector and element:

```
concat = F.udf(lambda v, e: Vectors.dense(list(v) + [e]), VectorUDT())
```

Apply udf to *inputs* and *temp* columns:

```
merged_df = df.select(concat(df.inputs, df.temp).alias('inputsMerged'))

merged_df.show()
+------------------+
|      inputsMerged|
+------------------+
|[1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0]|
|[0.0,1.0,0.0,10.0]|
+------------------+

merged_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- inputsMerged: vector (nullable = true)
```